# Google Cloud ConsoleでProject情報が表示されない。

Tags: google-cloud

こんにちは。
GCPのGoogle Compute Engineを利用しているのですが、数日前からGoogle Cloud Console画面でProject情報が表示されなくなりました。
VMインスタンスだけでなく、スナップショット、IAM、お支払いなどを選択しても、同様に表示されません。
Project名は表示されています。
[image: VMインスタンス選択画面]

ブラウザのキャッシュクリアや、他のブラウザでのアクセスも試してみましたが同じでした。
GCPのサポートチームに問い合わせようと問い合わせ方法を調べ、Google Cloud Consoleの「サポート」リンクから問い合わせするようなのですが、おそらくこの問題で「サポート」をクリックしたときも何も表示されず、問い合わせもできません。

問題の改善方法、もしくはGCPサポートチームへの問い合わせ方法を教えていただけないでしょうか。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 右上の？アイコンから順に辿っていけば https://cloud.google.com/support-hub?hl=ja 辺りがサポートページになりそうです。 / この質問自体は当サイトで扱う話題の範囲からは外れる気がします。

Comment: cubickさん。ありがとうございます。教えていただいたアドレスから先で、結局Google Cloud Consoleからサポートケースの提出するよう求められます。Consoleで何も表示されないためそれもできない状態です。カテゴリー違いとのこと、失礼しました。

Comment: サイトのカテゴリーから外れるようなので、こちらはCloseします。

Comment: この手の問題でよく見るのはアドブロッカーです。HTML や JavaScript を編集するような拡張機能を有効にしてないか確認してみてください。たとえばシークレットウィンドウでログインして開いてみたときも同じ表示になるでしょうか。

Comment: nekketsuuuさん。ありがとうございます。拡張機能の無効化、シークレットウインドウも試してみましたが同じでした。

Answer (score 0):

解決しました。
ウイルス対策ソフトによるブロックが原因でした。
お手数をおかけしました。

Answer (score 0):

自分の場合はブラウザの拡張機能（ChromeのDark Mode）が原因でした。今後、同様の問題が発生して検索でこのページに来る方へのご参考まで。